# SQL Join query with groupby

Tags: sql

I have two tables say T1 and T2, one(T1) which store Amount to be paid(AP), primary key Id and person Id (pid).

Other table(T2) store amount which is paid(Pay), this can be multiple as multiple payments can be made for a AP, also stores foreign key of T1 ID, and type.

Now what i want is SUM(AP) from t1 and SUM(Pay) groupby type.

The query i made for it,(not the exact query, but explains well what i am trying)

```
select SUM(AP) from T1 
where pid='someid' join left T2 on t1.id = t2.id, 
select Pay and type from T2, groupby type
```

Explanation

```
T1                T2

ID   AP            ID Pay Type

19   X             19 W  A
20   Y             19 Q  B
21   Z             21 R  B
                   21 S  B
```

Now what is happening, when it group by type, it takes 19,21,21 as B,together, and with that it gives me sum from T1 as twice Z + X , also for A, it is taking A and return sum as X

I receive data in format

```
1. AP:X, Pay:W, Type: A
2. AP: X+Z+Z, Pay:Q+R+S,Type B
```

What i required was sum from T1 and Sum from T2(based on id's from T1) group by type

I solved this using two different queries one for each, but not able to do in single query, it might be complex i know but wanted if possible.

Hope i tried to make question clear enough.

Comment: You will inevitably get ID=19 AP=x amount duplicated if you group by type. A solution might be to divide x among different types (percentage? First type gets entire amount?)

Comment: T1, no. Id is primary key for it.

Comment: I'm slightly confused as to what results you want.  Please could you also add an example of the output you *want*?

Comment: @Dems I want sum of data in T1 and Sum of data in T2 group by type, in a single query

Comment: You cannot because you have two types for single T1. So you will have one row from T1 listed twice (or more times if you have more types). This is not a problem if your report does not try to sum(AP). If it does, you will have to devise a way to split the value of AP among different types. You might display the value in first row and null it in next rows with same T1.ID, or you might arrange the value according to value in t2, in which case you might have trouble rounding numbers.

Comment: @amitchhajer - Sorry, rather than more words that loosely describe your needs, please could you use examples?  Edit the question and add a table of example inputs, with real numbers, and a table of the expected output, with real numbers?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're after?

```
select 
    vt1.id,
    vt1.ap,
    sum(t2.pay),
    t2.type

from (select id, sum(ap) as ap from t1 group by id) vt1
    left join t2 on vt1.id=t2.id
group by vt1.id, vt1.ap, t2.type
```

Comment: This is what it returns on above query: (formatting problem, added row number")
row `id  ap  sum(t2.pay)  type
1.  19          0  0  A
2.  19          0  0  B
3.  20          0  NULL NULL
4.  21   0  0  B`

Comment: it is not grouping by, right? here i have 3 entries for B